# Filter command line logs from built-in PHP server

Tags: php, bash, server, terminal, console

PHP has a built in [file server](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php) for testing and development purposes.

After a page was opened in a web browser, the console output of the server looks like this:

```
$ php -S localhost:8000
PHP 7.2.8 Development Server started at Sun Feb  9 23:09:17 2020
Listening on http://localhost:8000
Document root is /_PATHTOFILE_
Press Ctrl-C to quit.
[Sun Feb  9 23:09:19 2020] ::1:57697 [200]: /
[Sun Feb  9 23:09:19 2020] ::1:57698 [404]: /doesnt-exist.js - No such file or directory
```

**How can I filter out all lines that include `[200]`**, as I'm only interested in warnings and errors?

I have unsucessfully tried the following:

- `$ php -S localhost:8000 | grep --line-buffered --invert-match "200" | awk '{print $3}'`
- `$ php -S localhost:8000 | awk '!/200/{print $3}'`

Both commands don't filter the lines, they just log the following:

```
[Sun Feb  9 23:09:19 2020] ::1:57697 [200]: /
[Sun Feb  9 23:09:19 2020] ::1:57698 [404]: /doesnt-exist.js - No such file or directory
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: have you tried: `grep -v "\[200\]"`; what I don't know is if `php` is sending all messagesa to stdout or a mix of stdout and stderr; if the latter: `php -S localhost:8000 2>&1 | grep -v "\[200\]"` ... ?

Comment: given the sample output from your `php` call, what are you expecting to see as output?  your `awk` examples just print out the 3rd field of the matching lines ... is that what you really want to display (just the 3rd field)?

Comment: @markp, thank you! after doing a bit more [research](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/117502) I think I need to use `stdbuf` or `unbuffer` to process the php output while the PHP server is still running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logs of php -S ... are printed to stderr not stdout, you need to filter stderr also.
Without filtering:

```
$ php -S localhost:8888
PHP 5.6.40-0+deb8u7 Development Server started at Sun Feb 23 12:58:30 2020
Listening on http://localhost:8888
Document root is /home/sorin/tmp
Press Ctrl-C to quit.
[Sun Feb 23 12:58:33 2020] this is an error
[Sun Feb 23 12:58:33 2020] 127.0.0.1:52825 [200]: /test.php
^C
```

Redirecting stderr to stdout:

```
php -S localhost:8888 2>&1 | grep -v '\[200\]'
        [Sun Feb 23 12:59:41 2020] this is an error
```

Test file:

```
cat test.php
<?php

error_log('this is an error');
```